# Automatically start a computer when power turns on

Tags: boot, power, wake-on-lan

I installed Ubuntu on an old laptop (Lenovo T400) that I now use as a home server, running 24/7. I live in an area where long power outages are quite common, so if the power goes off there's a good chance the laptop's battery will be dead by the time the power comes.

I need a way to turn the laptop on when the power is back. I can't find a setting in the BIOS to turn it back on automatically, but I have an idea how I can turn it on. Its a bit of a hack, but I think it should work. I have a Raspberry Pi and my idea is to create a startup script that sends a wake on lan signal to the laptop. The Pi will power up when the power comes back and in that way turn the laptop back on.

Can anybody think of a better way to achieve this? Seems a bit silly having the pi running just for this purpose.

Comment: surprised its not in the bios, what make and model is the PC?

Comment: It's Lenovo T400. Perhaps I missed it. I'll check again

Comment: Checked again now, definitely not there

Comment: How long do the outages last?  You could supplement the laptop battery with a UPS battery.

Comment: I can look into that thanks. It typically lasts 2 hours